# Do unarmed attacks with silver gauntlets harm werewolves?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, attack, unarmed-combat, lycanthropy

Exactly like the title says, do silver gauntlets count as a weapon and do damage for the purpose of lycanthrope immunity to non-silver, non-magical attacks?

Comment: It depends, if the "silver gauntlets" is a weapon. Do you mean specific gauntlets or homebrewed ones?

Comment: I guess they'd be homebrewed? They're not in the PHB but seem like a fairly standard armor item. I guess the root of the question is can armor count as a weapon for the sake of unarmed attacks

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to me. I'd say it's a matter of whether werewolves are "allergic" to touch silver or if silver is simply required to reliably pierce werewolf skin. However, ruling out silver gauntlets for this reason would require that all blunt silver weapons be ruled out, because blunt weapons generally don't pierce skin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## RAW

Gauntlets ARE mentioned under various Armor types (Scale, Chain, Plate) in the PHB 144-5. Whether or not your DM will allow silver plating on those or armor of silver will be table dependent.

As weapons, Gauntlets are not listed in the 5e weapon list in the PHB on page 149. However, you may be able to do an Improvised Weapon which would deliver 1d4+STR MOD (PHB, 147-8) of damage bludgeoning (Pending DM approval). If they were made of silver, then it would bypass the immunity.

Otherwise, the attack would be from Silvered armor, if allowed from above, and deliver an unarmed melee attack for 1 bludgeoning damage that would bypass immunity from the silver.

## Homebrew

This becomes entirely up to you and your DM :) But it'd be a difficult argument to say they wouldn't bypass the immunity.